# Nullish coalescing testing for undefined

Tags: typescript

ive got this function that calls an API

```
interface getEventsPropsShape {
    eventId?: string;
    accountId?: string;
    eventsStartAfter?: string;
  }

  const getEvents = async ({
    eventId,
    accountId,
    eventsStartAfter,
  }: getEventsPropsShape): Promise<void> => {
    let apiUrl: string = '/v1/developer/events?limit=25&ascending=false';
    eventId !== undefined ?? (apiUrl += `&eventId=${eventId}`);
    accountId !== undefined ?? (apiUrl += `&accountId=${accountId}`);
    eventsStartAfter !== undefined ??
      (apiUrl += `&eventsStartAfter=${eventsStartAfter}`);
    const response = await get(apiUrl);
```

This works because it doesn't add `eventId` to apiUrl

```
let apiUrl: string = '/v1/developer/events?limit=25&ascending=false';
eventId !== undefined ?? (apiUrl += `&eventId=${eventId}`);
```

but this doesn't work because it ads `eventId = undefined` to the apiUrl

```
let apiUrl: string = '/v1/developer/events?limit=25&ascending=false';
eventId ?? (apiUrl += `&eventId=${eventId}`);
```

ultimately I'm looking to remove the if blocks from

```
    if (eventId) apiUrl += `&eventId=${eventId}`;
    if (accountId) apiUrl += `&accountId=${accountId}`;
    if (eventsStartAfter) apiUrl += `&eventsStartAfter=${eventsStartAfter}`;
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Or what is the behaviour you get? Also, what is `eventId`? Please supply a [mcve].

Comment: @VLAZ I've updated the question eventId is a string that could be passed to the function

Comment: But what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @VLAZ updated again, I'm expecting eventId to be tested for truthiness

Comment: OK... I mean, that's how `??` works - the right side *will only be executed* if the left side ***is*** `null` or `undefined`. In your case `eventId` ***is*** `undefined`. Therefore the right side of `??` is executed.

Comment: I guess I'm after a not null version eeek

Comment: "*ultimately I'm looking to remove the if blocks from*" and look how much time it saved you... it's about 20 minutes now after you've posted the question. Who knows how much more time would be wasted because you want to shorten your code with *literally* two characters. Per line. You're killing it on savings /s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `??` to `&&`. Example:

```js
let eventId = undefined;
let apiUrl = '/v1/developer/events?limit=25&ascending=false';

eventId && (apiUrl += `&eventId=${eventId}`);
console.log(apiUrl);

eventId = 'foo';
apiUrl = '/v1/developer/events?limit=25&ascending=false';
eventId && (apiUrl += `&eventId=${eventId}`);
console.log(apiUrl);
```

Or:

```js
let eventId = null;
let apiUrl = '/v1/developer/events?limit=25&ascending=false';

eventId !== undefined && (apiUrl += `&eventId=${eventId}`);
console.log(apiUrl);

eventId = 'foo';
apiUrl = '/v1/developer/events?limit=25&ascending=false';
eventId !== undefined && (apiUrl += `&eventId=${eventId}`);
console.log(apiUrl);
```